# ImportError: No module named win32service

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I am using odoo8 with python 2.7.9 (64 bit) on eclipse IDE. Python software got corrupted so I had to reinstall it.Now I am facing this new problem `ImportError: No module named win32service`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to install pywin32.

Either use `pip install pywin32` or download from GitHub `https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases`

Comment: All releases after 222 are exclusively on github.
https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/releases

Comment: Looks like you can use pip again (although it is "experimental"): `pip install pywin32`     https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32

Comment: version 303 is here https://pypi.org/project/pywin32/ in time of writing.
can't believe I'm excavating this after 6 years (:

Answer (score 11):

You need to install Piwin32 using pip

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Comment: Here's a the [latest reminder](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) for pip installations: ```Note that if you want to use pywin32 for "system wide" features, such as registering COM objects or implementing Windows Services, then you must run the following command from an elevated command prompt:

python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install```