# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32serviceutil'

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have a project which can be installed as Windows Service, but i have troubles getting it done.

Venv is prepared for this project with **pywin32** package installed (version 227). However while I am trying to run a python file from console with:

```
import win32serviceutil
```

I am getting a following error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32'

Things I tried:

- reinstallation of package, and reinstallation with `python -m pip install pywin32`
- changing import fashion to:

  `from win32 import win32serviceutil
   from win32.lib import win32serviceutil
   import win32.lib.win32serviceutil as win32serviceutil`
- Answers from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197879/importerror-no-module-named-win32service)

win32 is recognized as folder by PyCharm:

[image]

What is weird, I can run following command and install a Windows Service:

```
python MyPythonFile.py install
```

It does not return any errors. However trying to start the service with command:

```
python MyPythonFile.py start
```

returns:

> "Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"

In debug mode `python MyPythonFile.py debug` it returns:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32serviceutil'

Comment: Install 225 version

Comment: Note that if you want to use pywin32 for "system wide" features, such as registering COM objects or implementing Windows Services, then you must run the following command from an elevated command prompt (source https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32 )

Comment: @nithin I did that as well, it was one of the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38197879/importerror-no-module-named-win32service

Comment: @PySaad I am still getting same error

Comment: Try both pip install pywin32 and pip install pypiwin32

Comment: @nithin pypiwin32 is deprecated

Comment: @w8eight ah ok check this post if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49307303/installing-the-pypiwin32-module/49307408#49307408

Comment: @nithin I have pywin32 ver 223 and pypiwin32 installed now, and i cannot even debug a service now :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from this thread worked:
[Using PythonService.exe to host python service while using virtualenv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34696815/using-pythonservice-exe-to-host-python-service-while-using-virtualenv)

Code which I used to resolve it:

```
import os
import sys

service_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
source_directory = os.path.abspath(service_directory)
os.chdir(source_directory)
venv_base = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_directory, "..", "..", "venv"))
sys.path.append(".")
old_os_path = os.environ['PATH']
os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.join(venv_base, "Scripts")+ os.pathsep + old_os_path
site_packages = os.path.join(venv_base, "Lib", "site-packages")
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
import site
site.addsitedir(site_packages)
sys.real_prefix = sys.prefix
sys.prefix = venv_base
new_sys_path = list()
for item in list(sys.path):
    if item not in prev_sys_path:
        new_sys_path.append(item)
        sys.path.remove(item)
sys.path[:0] = new_sys_path
```

This code has to run before faulting imports

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked like this:

```
import os
import sys
import site

service_directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
source_directory = os.path.abspath(service_directory)
os.chdir(source_directory)
venv_base = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_directory, "venv"))
sys.path.append(".")
old_os_path = os.environ['PATH']
os.environ['PATH'] = os.path.join(venv_base, "Scripts") + os.pathsep + old_os_path
site_packages = os.path.join(venv_base, "Lib", "site-packages")
prev_sys_path = list(sys.path)
site.addsitedir(site_packages)
sys.real_prefix = sys.prefix
sys.prefix = venv_base

new_sys_path = list()
for item in list(sys.path):
    if item not in prev_sys_path:
        new_sys_path.append(item)
        sys.path.remove(item)
sys.path[: 0] = new_sys_path
```

Comment: I am sure it would help the community if you explained to us why and how you code would solve the OP's problem

Answer (score 0):

Good Work :)

To get this to work with me I had to change the path of the virtual env folder reflected in the following line to point to my venv folder

from this:
`venv_base = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_directory, "..", "..", "venv"))`

To this:
`venv_base = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(source_directory, "..", "..", "venv"))`

Comment: Your "from" is identical to your "to".